# SVN Integration/Pre-commit hooks with Trello

Tags: trello

Is there a simple way to get SVN Integration/Pre-commit hooks with Trello? I've been playing with the idea of switching my project from PivotalTracker to Trello, but I'm needing to find ways to fill in some of the gaps in order to get buy-in from management.

I've already had to find hacks to add story points, and it's a few too many clicks just to get the id of a card, but I haven't found a good way to provide some amount of SVN integration or pre-commit hooks so far, so I'm hoping somebody out there has a solution.

Comment: Did you find a solution? can you share it please?

Answer (score -3):

I'm looking into Cloudpipes:

https://www.cloudpipes.com/integrations/subversion/trello

Good luck!